# Can I pedal my bicycle backwards to move it backwards?

Tags: gears, pedals

Is there any changes I could do to my cycle so that I can make it move backwards?Just a question out of eagerness.

Comment: If you have a "fixie" you can pedal it backwards.  But your standard derailleur-style bike cannot be pedaled backwards, nor can the old-style "coaster brake" bike.

Comment: You could also do something like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70O8XZyycWk

Comment: Before the ubiquity of derailleurs there were bikes that ran one gear forwards and a climbing gear backwards. (Called a Retro-Direct http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retro-direct) I'd recommend befriending/becoming a machinist.

Comment: I suppose with an idler pulley mounted in a strategic place (and maybe a 9 speed chain) you might be able to run the chain in a figure-8 allowing you to move forward by pedaling backwards. Stranger things have happened.

Comment: Like http://www.frankb.us/gears/ ?

Comment: Hey, what do you mean "out of eagerness"? Are you actually keen on building such a bike, or were you just curious?

Comment: I'm not seeing any answers yet for "moving backwards", however, I guess one could create a n+1 speed internal hub that would rotate in the opposite direction in the "+1" gear.  I think some trikes and quads would benefit from it.  I'm sure it would be a beast of a hub.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's stopping you from pedalling backwards?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3851/whats-stopping-you-from-pedalling-backwards)

Comment: A "fixie" is the most straight-forward way to move backwards.  (If saying "straight-forward way to move backwards" even makes any sense.)  That or a unicycle.

Answer (score 5):

To sum up all the comment answers, which provide you with a wealth of options:

- [The backwards bike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70O8XZyycWk)
- [Retro-direct gearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retro-direct)
- [The Tri Via gearing system](http://www.frankb.us/gears/)

Some parts of these look rather easy to fabricate such as the idler arms or connecting two forks together. The rear hub is going to be the most difficult part since you have to build two sets of engagement together and fit it in the space of a regular hub.

Answer (score 1):

A British gentleman by the name of Drew Buck actually rode the 2007 Paris-Brest-Paris (a mere 770 miles (approx.) in 90 hours) on a 2-speed 1913 Hirondelle, with a low gear engaged by pedalling backwards in the Retro-Direct style.

Links to articles on the ride are [here](http://www.nrtoone.com/home/?p=404), which has a diagram explaining how the gearing works, and [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-somerset-25238228), which is a link to a BBC article on the ride.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice article by Kent Peterson on a [retro-direct bicycle](http://kentsbike.blogspot.com/2008/12/retro-direction-perfection.html)

Comment: Interesting to see someone actually use one.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch it here on 0:35 and on 1:05

Answer (score 0):

Just to actually answer the question, even though it's not as interesting as some of the comments: yes, you can probably convert your bike to a fixed gear, and then if you can learn to steer backwards and not fall over, you will be able to pedal it backwards.

There are several questions about fixed gear conversions, here's a starting point: 
[Planning on building a fixed-gear/single-speed from an old Schwinn World. What new parts will I need?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16551/planning-on-building-a-fixed-gear-single-speed-from-an-old-schwinn-world-what-n)